# Reset default SQL Server Management Studio column width for `Edit Top 200 Rows` gridview

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How can I increase the default column width for `Edit Top 200 Rows` gridview?
The default seems to be 16 bytes but I would like to set a new default that is applied to all the gridview columns whenever `Edit Top 200 Rows` is selected.
Thanks.

Comment: Why? Just export the whole table (or the records you need) to excel, edit them and then import them. Or just double click on the heading and the column will be automatically expand.

Comment: I know I can export to another tool and resize that tool's column widths but for my purposes this represents extra effort.  When I double click on the Gridview column heading nothing happens - columns don't resize.  Am I not double clicking the right way?  Please advise.

Comment: @Joe it will resize only if you are currently seeing a value that is being cut short of it's length.

Answer (score -2):

Just Follow this Simple Step...

**Tools --> Options- -> SQL Server Object Explorer --> Commands**

Change Value for Edit Top  Rows Command to a Higher Number

[image]

**Note:-** In above Image you can change the number of rows can be Edited..

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh.  What I want to do is increase the default width of the columns displayed.  I don't want to increase the number of rows displayed.

Comment: This is not what OP asked how to do.